# Insert row into table where value not in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with three columns: `Day`, `Key`, `Value`. If there is a value absent from the `Key` column, I want to be able to insert it:

```
DAY | KEY | VALUE
------------------
Mon   Run   50    
Mon   Bike  20
Tues  Run   25
Tues  Bike  60
Wed   Run   20
Wed   Swim  5
```

I want to be able to identify the row with the missing 'Bike' value from the column and insert it. So there would be an additional row

```
Wed Bike 20
```

How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: By the logic, swim should be flagged too - for Mon & Tues, right?

Comment: I want to be able to choose that value. So I'd Look to see which days didn't include bike, then add it to those days.

Comment: So you don't know the value beforehand?  User interaction/decision means at least two queries - one to see the list, the second to implement the change(s).

Comment: It can be a fixed value. For example it always just looks for 'Bike'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try this? It's the hard-coded approach:

```
INSERT INTO <yourtable> (day, key, value)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.day AS day, 'Bike' as key, 20 as value
FROM
    <yourtable> AS t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT day, key FROM <yourtable> WHERE key='Bike') AS t2
    ON t1.day = t2.day
WHERE t2.key IS NULL;
```

Or if you can, please use stored procedures (which will allow you to choose the activity and value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertActivityWhereMissing 
      @activity VARCHAR(50)
    , @activityValue INT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO <yourtable> (day, key, value)
    SELECT t1.day AS day, @activity as key, @activityValue as value
    FROM
        (SELECT day FROM <yourtable> GROUP BY day) AS t1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (SELECT day, key FROM <yourtable> WHERE key = @activity) AS t2
        ON t1.day = t2.day
    WHERE t2.key IS NULL;
END
```

This way, you can perform the same action for any particular `"activity"` (I'm just naming it that way, but I'm referring to `Run`, `Bike`, `Swim` or anything else)

Comment: Gosh, that's so weird :( I recreated the tables and executed my code (minus the insert) and the select returned his desired result... Then I ran the insert and it worked, and when I did the select again nothing returned anymore since the wednesday 'bike' row was previously inserted :(